# Move absolute div outside the parent

Tags: css

Is it possible to move an absolute positioned `div` outside the parent's borders?

I tried (less) `left:calc(~'0%-15px')` but does not seem to work :)

```
.dif-links {
    background: pink; width: 25px; height: 100px; 
    position: absolute; text-align: center;
    left:calc(~'0%-15px')
}
```

I have an article and I would like to maintain the "share" div outisde the article body, this is why I used the absolute position, but now just move it to the left side of parent seems to be complicated...

[image]

**Here is [my pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyjOvP)**

Comment: Use `margin-left:-15px;`

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the parent is its containing block (e.g. has `position: relative`), the easiest way is

```css
position: absolute;
right: 100%;
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">Foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 100% it takes the fulll screen

Comment: @Serge Not sure if you meant out-of-screen. That will happen if the parent is not the containing block.

Comment: ok, so I should modify the parent's position to relative... if possible

Answer (score 3):

Just set a margin-left of -25px.

Comment: @Serge I just tested in Your pen example and it's working (??!!) and You don't need that `left:...`. Use for `margin-left` how much You need `px`, but negative value.

Comment: Absolute position is removed from page flow. There should be no problem moving it from its parent container.

Comment: I tested the positive margin and didn't seen the difference, but with negative I see now! :)

Answer (score 0):

The below css seems to work like you expected. I have not used calc() method but i am sure you can tweak it now to fit your need.

```css
.dif-links {
  background: pink;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;left:365px;
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Happy Styling.

Comment: "hardcoded" position will be broken if the window is resized

Answer (score 0):

i have try like this please check,

```
.dif-links{
background: pink; width: 25px; height: 100px; position: absolute; text-align: center;left:-15px; top:0;}

.container {    
    width: @w;
    height: calc(~'100% - '@h);
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: @h;
  position:relative;
}
```